# iOS with parse error on fetching data

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsarray, parse-platform

So, I have a tableviewcontroller that lists many "profiles" and when I click on one of them I'm sent to a viewcontroller that receives the objectId from the segue.

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showProfile"]) {
    ProfileViewController *profile = segue.destinationViewController;
    profile.objectId = [self.currentDog valueForKey:@"objectId"];
}
```

When I reach the ProfileViewController, I want to fetch the profile data using that objectId.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"dog"];
[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", object);
    }
}];
```

But this part `[query getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.objectId block:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error)` is throwing an exception.

**The Error:**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: __NSArrayI'
```

I can't understand it and can't find the solution online.
At my header file I got `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *objectId;`

Comment: I just want to make sure that you understand what you were doing wrong, because some people ask questions and then just copy and paste the answers and expect them to work, then just move on. You were trying to save a PFObject to a property of type array, which is why you were getting the error you were. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is when you select a cell, (from the array you're using, or a query like you do now) get the object that is in that cell, and save it to a property "selectedObject" that you can create in your header file. Now, when you perform your segue, just do `profile.objectId = self.selectedObject.objectId;`

Comment: currentDog is an NSArray.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
...
   
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"dog"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:cell.textLabel.text];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:currentUser];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"ERROR: %@",error);
        }else{
            self.currentDog = objects;
            [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showProfile" sender:self];
        }
    }];
    
}

Comment: @FernandoClaussen okay so it is an array of pfobjects. I see the problem, I will update my answer.

Comment: But that is exactly what I'm doing. The query returns an NSArray called objects.

I'm assigning this value to a NSArray property declared in the header called currentDog.

When I'm preparing to segue, I'm assigning it using profile.objectId = [self.currentDog valueForKey:@"objectId"];

This part works fine. If I go into profileViewController.m and use NSLog(@"%@", self.objectId) it returns the actual ID

But if I try querying with that ID, it throws this exception
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: __NSArrayI'

Comment: @FernandoClaussen Hmmm, would you try it my way just to see?

Comment: If I try your way it doesn't compile.

Property 'objectId' not found on object of type 'NSArray *'

Comment: @FernandoClaussen That doesn't sound right at all. Can I see the code?

Comment: @FernandoClaussen selectedDog should be a PFObject. In didSelectRowAtIndexPath: self.selectedDog = [self.allDogs objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];